# listview is displaing 3 results together in one line

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

i am trying to develop an rss reader
first i was preparing an arraylist variable menu items 2000 contains (title,link,description) to display it in a list item 
but the listview displayed the three strings together in one line as like in the image:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8QX3.png)

here is the source:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems2000 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
TextView textview10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview10);
TextView textview11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview11);
TextView textview12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview12);
ListView listview10 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview10);
//----------------------------------------------
Document doc = getDomElement(contentAsString2); // getting DOM element
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
// looping through all item nodes <item>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
     //creating new HashMap
     HashMap<String, String> map2000 = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
     map2000.put(KEY_TITLE, getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
     map2000.put(KEY_LINK, getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
     map2000.put(KEY_DESC, getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
     // adding HashList to ArrayList
     menuItems2000.add(map2000);
 }
 //---add menuItems to liat view------------------
 textview10.setText("finish");
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        listviewrss.this,
                        menuItems2000,
                        R.layout.listviewrss,
                        new String[]{KEY_TITLE,KEY_LINK,KEY_DESC},
                        new int[]{R.id.textview10, R.id.textview11,
                        R.id.textview12 } );
  listview10.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some errors in your row layout. Try to check it again

Answer (score 0):

here is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.centryapps.rss1.listviewrss">

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview10"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview11"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listview10"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview12"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listview10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Please edit the original question with this xml,it's not an answer so please delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinearLayout with ListView as a children and create seperate xml file for design of one row of ListView -there you should put yours TextViews, EditTexts etc.